# React Helmet adds <script type="application/ld+json"> outside </html>

Tags: reactjs, widget, frontend, react-helmet

I have implemented a third party widget on my website to get Rich Snippets stars. The issue is that the Google-bot and Google structured-data testing-tool do not recognise the ld+json markup because it's outside the **html** tag. i have used React Helmet to force the script inside the **head** tag but in vain!

[image]

Here is the code of my app :

```
return (
        <div className="cleanslate widget-box">
            {comp}
            <Helmet>
                <script type="application/ld+json">
                {`
                    {
                        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
                        "@type": "CreativeWorkSeries",
                        "name": "${this.state.name}",
                        "aggregateRating": {
                            "@type": "AggregateRating",
                            "ratingValue": "${this.state.rating}",
                            "bestRating": "10",
                            "ratingCount": "${this.state.voters}"
                        }
                    }
                `}
                </script>
            </Helmet>
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try JSON.stringify() on your json. Like so:

```
const ldJson = {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Blogs",
    "item": "https://www.speblog.org"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": head.title,
    "item": window.location.href
  }]
};

<script type="application/ld+json">
  {JSON.stringify(ldJson)}
</script>
```

Didn't work for me until I did that (react-helment@^5.2.1)

Comment: This seems to be a requirement in Next.js and probably all React apps. I was going crazy trying to figure out why this would validate on Google's tool but not in my app - makes sense now.

Comment: This worked great in a typescript React app for me.